# Not sure is the correct way in handling file asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm using this code to write a group of files on disk:

```
var savingTasks = games.Games.Select(t=>{
                var path = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(savePath,Path.GetFileName(t.Url)),"pgn");
                Log.Information($"trying to save game in:{path}");
                var fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                opened.Add(fs);
                var sr = new StreamWriter(fs);
                writers.Add(sr);
                var tsk =  sr.WriteAsync(t.Pgn);
                return tsk;
                });
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(savingTasks);
    var flushing = writers.Select(u=>u.FlushAsync());
    await Task.WhenAll(flushing);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     Log.Fatal($"Cannot write to file:{e}");
     throw e;
}
finally
{
     opened.ForEach(s => s.Close());
}
```

In some steps I'm not convinced I'm doing in the best way, even if the code works just fine.
The portion not convincing me is how I handle the closing: I created a group of tasks in the `Select`, but I had to keep track on the opened file in order to close them ( see finally ), and in a similar way, I had to manage the collection of `StreamWriter` ( see `writers` ).
This is not convincing me, is there a better approach?

Comment: Why are you writing all the files concurrently? For better performance?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias   since I'm dealing with I/O operation I think doing async will improve system resource usage

Comment: You can still write the files asynchronously, but one at a time. By writing all of them concurrently you may asking too much from the underlying hardware (especially if it's a classic electro-mechanical hard disk drive).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias your topic is very interesting. Actuallt I posted a question here abouth that, but some moderator deleted it as "opinion based". Do you have some resource on that topic?

Comment: I don't have specific articles to link, but it is frequently noted in related questions by many programmers that multiple simultaneous I/O operations on traditional disks can slow things down quite a lot, instead of offering speed improvement. This is supported by my own improvised experiments, and it is also quite logical if you know the general principals of [how hard disks work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Performance_characteristics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over complicating things.

You should use a `using` block for your `FileStream` and `StreamWriter`, which takes care of flushing / closing when they are disposed.

By awaiting `WriteAsync` rather than returning the `Task` it generates, will ensure your `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` are not disposed of too soon:

```
var savingTasks = games.Games
    .Select(async t =>
    {
        var path = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(savePath,Path.GetFileName(t.Url)),"pgn");
        Log.Information($"trying to save game in:{path}");

        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            await sr.WriteAsync(t.Pgn);
        }
    });

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(savingTasks);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Fatal($"Cannot write to file:{e}");
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is the first version of my code and was not working, there was some strange behavior on trying to write on closed files...

Comment: There is another issue. A FileStream must be opened in async mode by using a constructor overload that takes `FileOptions.Asynchronous` in order that true I/O async is used. Also never use `throw e` just use `throw` to maintain the stacktrace.

Comment: @FelicePollano  The code doesn’t write on closed files, it creates a new file, writes to it and closes it.

Comment: by the way, code you suggest does not compile, since awaiting sr.WriteAsync does not return a task...

Comment: @FelicePollano Just change `t =>` to `async t =>`.

Comment: @ckuri Yes, I've added `useAsync: true` so that the I/O can be done async at OS level. Omitting the `async` keyword was a typo.

Comment: Correct, Maybe my first version with using(...) was leaking the await, and I did the correction in the wrong way

Answer (score 2):

I will move the `FlushAsync` to the `finally` because if an exception jumps during the execution of the tasks they won't be cleared. 
In addition, I would recommend for cleanliness to do everything in one method like the next:

```
var savingTasks = games.Games.Select(t=>ExecuteGameMethod(t));
try
{
     await Task.WhenAll(savingTasks);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.Fatal($"Cannot write to file:{e}");
        throw;
}


public async Task ExecuteGameMethod(Game game)
{
    var path = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(savePath,Path.GetFileName(game.Url)),"pgn");
    Log.Information($"trying to save game in:{path}");
    using(var fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite,bufferSize:4096, isAsync:true ))
    using(var sr = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        await sr.WriteAsync(game.Pgn);
        await sr.FlushAsync();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to specify `FileOptions.Asynchronous` in the FileStream constructor in order to use async I/O, otherwise internally it’s still synchronous just wrapped in async. Also never use `throw e`, just use `throw` to maintain the stacktrace.

Comment: @FelicePollano just updated a little bit to match your variables (and the async on the filestream and the method header)  but I don't see why it would not compile.